# Insufficient SSL certificate pinning in an native Android app

Tags: tls, android, java, certificate-pinning

I have implemented Certificate Pinning in a prototype of an android app. Here are the steps I followed:

1. Converted `.crt` file to `.bks` file
2. Added the `.bks` file to the asset folder in project structure
3. Loaded the above file during API call using `trustmanagerfactory`

The security auditor is saying this implementation is weak and can be easily broken using FRIDA or any other bypass tool.

Is there any better way to implement SSL pinning so that the above tool can't intercept the network calls?

P.S: I am using DefaultHTTPClient for API calls.

I added the public hash of the certificate in the network security config file and yet the tool is able to bypass it.
[image]

Comment: If the attacker can run your app on his device, he can bypass whatever protection you employ, it's just a question of time.